# Counting number of first character in given string (assembly language 8086)

Tags: assembly, emu8086

```
    MOV dh, 0    ; current charachter 
    MOV si, offset all_text   
jmp1: 
    INC si     
    MOV bx, [si-1]       
    CMP bx, [si-1]        
    JNE c1   
    INC dh        
c1:                  
    CMP [si-1], '$'     
    JNE jmp1 

    MOV AH, 2     
    MOV DL, 10     
    INT 21h


    ADD dh, 48     
    MOV ah, 2h
    MOV dl, dh       
    INT 21h        ; print num of current char
```

I am trying to count 1st character in given string, but result is always more than I need 
for example: 
input: aabaaba
output: 8
but output should be 5 
I could not figured out what is a problem.

Comment: `MOV bx, [si-1]; CMP bx, [si-1]` ... you are comparing every letter to **itself**. Also, characters are 1 byte so don't use 16 bit operations.

Comment: thanks for response, I got what you mean, I changed but I have still problem. I think problem is with incrementation of si. but I could not solve

Comment: Did you change to using 8-bit operand-size?  If not, then you're checking pairs of characters at once.  Look at register contents with the emu8086 debugger to see what you're loading.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah I changed, I checked debugger and problem with CMP operation

Answer (score 0):

```
    MOV dh, 1    ; current charachter   
 MOV si, offset all_text  

    MOV bh, [si]

jmp1:   
    inc si
    CMP bh, [si]        
    JNE c1   
    INC dh

c1:             
    CMP [si], '$'     
    JNE jmp1 

    MOV AH, 2      ; print
    MOV DL, 10     ; new line after pressing enter
    INT 21h

    ADD dh, 48     
    MOV ah, 2h
    MOV dl, dh       
    INT 21h        ; print num of current char
```

Comment: Oh, this is supposed to count how many matches of `str[0]` there are?  Not how many transitions to a new character?  That was 5 in both cases, and your question was loading inside the loop so I assumed you were supposed to be counting any time `str[i] != str[i-1]`.  Anyway, this would be a better answer if you commented your code and/or explained in English what was wrong / how you fixed it.